# I want to update my series dynamically on highcharts with a click & also bring it to the original way by clicking on an other button (#previous)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This is my fiddle ,It's displaying the same data when clicked on previous button after the new button
   http://jsfiddle.net/n4L8s3m0/2/

```
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({
   series:data1
});

// For New Data

$('#new').click(function() {
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

  chart.update({
    series: series
  });
  });

//Back to same series

$('#previous').click(function() {
 var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
 chart.update({
     series: data1

  });
  });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts for performance mutates an original data array, so data values in `data1` variable are the same as in `series` variable after first update. As a solution you need to create a new array with data, for examply by returning it from a function.

```
    function getData1() {
        return [...]
    }

    function getSeries() {
        return [...]
    }

    $('#container').highcharts({
        series: getData1()
    });

    // For New Data
    $('#new').click(function() {
        ...
        chart.update({
            series: getSeries()
        });
    });

    //Back to same series
    $('#previous').click(function() {
        ...
        chart.update({
            series: getData1()
        });
    });
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qk3rLa5v/